# What do %/% and %% mean?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've recently seen code like this:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %.% mutate(carb_10 =  carb %/% 10)
```

And this....

```
mtcars %.% mutate(carb_10 =  carb %% 10)
```

Can anyone explain what %/% and %% do in above code?

Comment: Yes, `help("%/%")`.

Comment: The usual keyboard shortcut (assigned to control + H) to bring up help didn't work on %/%, so I didnt think it had a help page. But I manually searching for it has indeed brought up a help page

Comment: In addition, searching Google with 'r [INSERT SEARCH TERM]' normally works great. But searching for 'r %/%' and 'r %%' returned nothing relevant. So I tried both my usual help channels and both apparently provided no clues as to what %/% or %% meant, leaving me with no choice but to post here.

Comment: (I think 10 downvotes is excessive for this question. The user was unlucky with the context.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `?"%%"` help page

> `%%` indicates x mod y and `%/%` indicates integer division. It is guaranteed that `x == (x %% y) + y * ( x %/% y )` (up to rounding error) unless y == 0 where the result of `%%` is NA_integer_ or NaN (depending on the typeof of the arguments).

Answer (score 14):

**In R:**

- %% is the modulo operator
- example: 5 %% 3    will be equal to 2 as it is the remainder obtained on the integral division of 5 by 3

**In Python**, you can do it by simply using: **%**

- 5 % 3

---

**In R:**

- %/% is the integer division operator
- example: 5 %/% 3   will be equal to 1 as it is the quotient obtained on the integer division of 5 by 3

**In Python,** you can do it by simply using: **//**

- 5 // 3

Answer (score 7):

Help is available on operators, but you have to escape them first, otherwise they are interpreted literally.

For example

```
?`%%`
```

Opens the "Arithmetic" help page, which includes help on both `%%` and `%/%` as well as `+`, `*` etc.  You can also access the page like this:

```
?Arithmetic
```

Your IDE may not know that operators need to be quoted.  In fact, help is 'smart' and can provide help on multiply-dispatched calls where argument type affects which function is actually executed:

so simply quoting all text and passing it to help would not work correctly.

---

## Offtopic on backquoting

Back quoting the operator returns an standard function (not a string), which can be useful in other circumstances, for instance, finding out how it works:

```
> `%\%`
function (e1, e2)  .Primitive("%%")
```

Assignment;

```
> add <- `%+%`
> `%MYADD%` <- add
> 1 %MYADD% 2
[1] 3
```

Or supplying it to a higher-order function such as apply, Map, Reduce, do.call etc.  For example, here's how we can rewrite 'sum':

```
> Reduce(`+`,1:10,0)
[1] 55
```

Answer (score -3):

```
b <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);
b[b %% 3 == 1]  
#1/3=0...1 ; 4/3=1...1 ;7/3=2...1 ; ANS：1,4,7,10 ，remainder=1;
b[b %/% 3 == 1] 
#3/3=1...0 ; 4/3=1...1 ;5/3=1...2 ; ANS：1,4,7,10 ，quotient =1 ;
```

Comment: Please consider to explain in your answer how this solves the problem stated in the original question.